# Memory Game Mouse click limit and counter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, mouseevent

I am trying to limit the amount of clicks allowed per turn to two, because once I press 3 cards fast enough the game can turn over a card that has a match.

**- HTML**

```
 <div class ="container col-md-12">

        <section class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" data-card-type="1" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/cookie.JPG"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" data-card-type="1" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/cookie.JPG"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" data-card-type="2" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/baronIlanYahav.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" data-card-type="2" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/baronIlanYahav.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="cardsContainer">
            <div class="card" data-card-type="3" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/beverlyHills.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="card" data-card-type="3" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/beverlyHills.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="card" data-card-type="4" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/bulgaria.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="card" data-card-type="4" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/bulgaria.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="card" data-card-type="5" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/mrMustache.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <section class="cardsContainer">
        <div class="card" data-card-type="5" onclick="flip($(this))">
                <div class="front"><img src="../images/backsideBlue.png"></div>
                <div class="back"><img src="../images/mrMustache.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

- **JS**

```
 function flip(card) {
     if (!selectedCards[card.data("card-type")]) {


     }
     if (!$(card).hasClass("flipped")) {

         $(card).toggleClass('flipped');

         previous = $(card);


         if (!card1) {
             card1 = $(card);
         } else {
             card2 = $(card);
             var cardType1 = card1.data("card-type");
             var cardType2 = card2.data("card-type");
             if (checkMatch(cardType1, cardType2)) {
                 addPoint();
                 addSelectedCards(cardType2);
                 disableCards();
             } else {
                 setTimeout(function () {
                         flipBack();
                         //clean cards vars
                         resetCards();
                     },
                     1000);//set timer 1 sec to flip back
             }
         }

     }
```

Please help! **Bonus** I would really appreciate an idea on how to count clicks so I could later combine it with the final score.

Comment: Could you possibly add a `demo` in a `jsfiddle` or `snippet` so that we can easily help with you.. There are some functions which aren't present in your given code..

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point, but you could simply add to a count per click, and check the count each time. You know, good old ``if (click > 10) { dont do anything on click } else { do something on click } ``. And yes, a JSFiddle wouldn't go a miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can block a third click simply by counting the flipped cards:

```
function flip() { 
  if ( $('.flipped').length > 2 ) {
    return false;
  }

  // do your thing [...]
}
```

Count Clicks via a global variable or

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: sorry for my extreme N00bness, but where should I put this limiter?

Comment: Sorry for my inability to understand your code completely.

Comment: Put the limiter at the beginning of flip() and end the function prematurely. Of course you have to test for cards flipped greater or equal to two. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Furthermore you should not use global variables but get the cards via Selectors all the time. Also seperate the flipping from the match checking imnsho